# How to specify credentials for custom maven private repo

Tags: java, maven

I have used this article (https://gist.github.com/fernandezpablo85/03cf8b0cd2e7d8527063) for creating a custom maven repo, and it works. But now I have a problem with a private repo. How can I specify credentials for the private repo?

Comment: This article might help: https://dev.to/fk/creating-private-maven-gradle-repository-2np3

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set in `.m2/settings.xml` file

Like This:

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>private-repo</id>
            <username>xyz</username>
            <password>${pass}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

And in `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
    ...
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>private-repo</id>
            <url>${private-repo.url}</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have tried it, but it doesn't work. Should I specify settings.xml file location in pom.xml?

Answer (score 1):

A `settings.xml` file is usually found in a couple of places:

- Global settings in Mavens home directory: `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`
- User settings in the user’s home: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

If both files exist, their contents are merged. Configurations from the user settings take precedence.

If your settings doesn't apply you can try to override the default `settings.xml` file location by adding `--settings` flag to your `mvn ...` command.

sources:

- https://www.baeldung.com/maven-settings-xml#settings-level
- https://www.baeldung.com/maven-settings-xml#3-override-the-default-location